# How would i come across looping my Mastermind game

Tags: java, bluej

How would i come across looping my game of Mastermind so that it would play 10 times and if the user does not guess it in 10 turns it ends but if they do guess it the program ends and they win. I know i could use a do while statement but that would take alot and im not sure how i would come across it.

```
  // The purpose is to win a game of Mastermind against a computer player.
// 5/26/15
// Matthew Soutar

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

    class Mastermind 
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            //Welcome
            System.out.println ("Welcome to Matthew's game of Mastermind!");
            int[] Secret_code = Mystery();
            int[] Gameboard = Gameboard (Secret_code);
            int resultCount = Comparing (Secret_code, Gameboard);
            int resultCount2 = Comparing2 (Secret_code, Gameboard);
            //Goodbye
            System.out.println ("Thank you for playing.");            
            //Winner
            if (Gameboard[0] == Secret_code[0] && Gameboard[1] == Secret_code[1] && Gameboard[2] == Secret_code[2] && Gameboard[3] == Secret_code[3])
            System.out.println ("You have won this game of Mastermind!");
        }


        public static int[] Mystery () {

            //Random
            int secretcode = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;
            int secretcode1 = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;
            int secretcode2 = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;
            int secretcode3 = (int)(6*Math.random()) + 1;

           //Secretcode print
           System.out.println (secretcode);
           System.out.println (secretcode1);
           System.out.println (secretcode2);
           System.out.println (secretcode3);

           //Array
           int [] Secret_code;
           Secret_code = new int [4];
           Secret_code[0] = secretcode;
           Secret_code[1] = secretcode1;
           Secret_code[2] = secretcode2;
           Secret_code[3] = secretcode3;

            return Secret_code;
    }
        public static int[] Gameboard (int[] Secret_code) {
        //Variable Declaration
        int guess1, guess2, guess3, guess4;
        Scanner Guess = new Scanner (System.in);

        //User Guess's
         System.out.println ("What is the number one peg in my code?");
         guess1 = Guess.nextInt();
         System.out.println ("What is the number two peg in my code?");
         guess2 = Guess.nextInt();
         System.out.println ("What is the number three peg in my code?");
         guess3 = Guess.nextInt();
         System.out.println ("What is the number four peg in my code?");
         guess4 = Guess.nextInt();

         //Array
         int [] Gameboard;
         Gameboard = new int [4];
         Gameboard[0] = guess1;
         Gameboard[1] = guess2;
         Gameboard[2] = guess3;
         Gameboard[3] = guess4;

         return Gameboard;
}
        public static int Comparing (int[] Secret_code, int[] Gameboard){
         int resultCount = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         if (Gameboard[i] == Secret_code[i])
          resultCount++;
            }
    System.out.println("You got " + resultCount + " correct in the right spot."); 
    return resultCount;
    }
    public static int Comparing2 (int[] Secret_code, int[] Gameboard){
              int resultCount2 = 0;
              int i = 0;
              for (int e = 0; e < 4; e++) {
                if (Gameboard[e] == Secret_code[i])
                 resultCount2++;
                }
                System.out.println ("You got " + resultCount2 + " correct but in the wrong spot");
                return resultCount2;
    }
    }
```

Comment: you can also use a `for` loop and simply terminate it with a `break` statement when the user has won.

Comment: how would i come across doing that @Dragondraikk

Comment: What do you mean by "come across it"?

Comment: lowkey how would u do it

Comment: Well you've already used multiple for loops. This one would be the same. `break` simply terminates the loop and continues after its closing bracket.

Comment: oh so i would just add it in my main method and ok thanks

Comment: @Dragondraikk i did the for loop and break but i dont think that i have done it correctly this is what i get :                                                        for (Tally = 0; Tally <10; Tally++){
                if (Secret_code[0] == Gameboard[0] && Secret_code[1] == Gameboard[1] && Secret_code[2] == Gameboard[2] && Secret_code[3] == Gameboard[3]){
                break;
            }
            
        }

Comment: You need to also keep your user input in that loop, otherwise you'll be checking against the same input multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

See this; might be this what you are looking for:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Mastermind {

    static int numAttempts = 10, numGuess = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Matthew's game of Mastermind! Guess : "
                + pw(numGuess) + " random numbers");

        int[] Secret_code = Mystery();
        Scanner Guess = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (numAttempts-- > 0) {
            int[] Gameboard = Gameboard(Guess);

            int resultCount = Comparing(Secret_code, Gameboard);

            if (resultCount == numGuess) {
                System.out.println("You have won this game of Mastermind!");
                break;
            } else
                compareWrongSpot(Secret_code, Gameboard);

            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");

        Guess.close();
    }

    public static int[] Mystery() {

        int[] Secret_code = new int[numGuess];

        for (int i = 0; i < numGuess; i++) {
            Secret_code[i] = (int) (6 * Math.random()) + 1;
            System.out.println(Secret_code[i]);
        }

        return Secret_code;
    }

    public static int[] Gameboard(Scanner Guess) {

        int[] Gameboard = new int[numGuess];

        for (int i = 1; i <= numGuess; i++) {
            System.out.println("What is the number " + pw(i)
                    + " peg in my code?");
            Gameboard[i - 1] = Guess.nextInt();
        }

        return Gameboard;
    }

    public static String pw(int n) {
        String one[] = { " ", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six",
                "seven", "eight", "Nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve",
                "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen",
                "eighteen", "nineteen" };

        return one[n];
    }

    public static int Comparing(int[] Secret_code, int[] Gameboard) {
        int resultCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numGuess; i++)
            if (Gameboard[i] == Secret_code[i])
                resultCount++;

        System.out.println("You got " + resultCount
                + " correct in the right spot.");
        return resultCount;
    }

    public static int compareWrongSpot(int[] Secret_code, int[] Gameboard) {
        int resultCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numGuess; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < numGuess; j++)
                if (Gameboard[i] == Secret_code[j])
                    resultCount++;

        System.out.println("You got " + resultCount
                + " correct but in the wrong spot");
        return resultCount;
    }
}
```